# Define typeof values from Input, please

Tags: javascript, html

Question: How do I determine the typeof value entered in input? When checking typeof, it always shows string if the string is not empty. I rummaged through a bunch of forums, but I never found one. Please help me. This is what it looks like for me now:

```js
function submit_8(){
    var text = document.querySelector('.text_mes').value;
    console.log(typeof text);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="text_mes">
<button type="button" onclick="submit_8()">Вычислить</button>
```

Expected output: For example, if I enter 8, it's number, if I enter true, it's boolean

Comment: The posted code is not java - did you mean javascript?

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/ and posted code is no Java - please edit the question (link below tags) and remove the [tag:java] tag,eventually adding the correct one

Comment: `HTMLInputElement.prototype.value` is **always** a `string`.

Comment: And how to get the original value type from HTML?

Comment: For example, if I enter 8, it's number, if I enter true, it's boolean

Comment: @Maxim The value is a string, you have to convert it into another type on your own. For  `.value` to be a number, you have to use [`type="number"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) For a boolean, a checkbox and the [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#attr-checked) property

Comment: @ `.value` will be a string even with `<input type="number" />`. To get a number, you'd have to use `.valueAsNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

For numbers, you can try to convert the string using `Number(value)` or and check if the result is a number using `isNaN(value)`.

For booleans there is no such built-in conversion, but it's easy to build:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', ({target:{value}}) => {
  let typedValue = value;
  if (!isNaN(Number(value))) typedValue = Number(value);
  switch (value.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'true':
      typedValue = true;
      break;
    case 'false':
      typedValue = false;
      break;
  }
  console.log(`value: ${typedValue}, type: ${typeof typedValue}`);
})
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks! And how do I accept all the other types? How to solve this via typeof?

Comment: You cannot solve this via `typeof`. For the other types, you will have to write checks as well. Which types come to your mind?

Comment: Thanks, I get it. For example, I will have the text type "underfined", and I won't use it via typeof from input?